# Get index columns total size

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

To get primary key columns total size, (not index size itself, so `SELECT pg_table_size(indexrelid) FROM pg_index WHERE ..` is not solution in this case), I'm using dynamic query like this:

```
DO $$       
    DECLARE
    v_query TEXT;
    v_result BIGINT;
BEGIN
    SELECT 'SELECT COALESCE( SUM( pg_column_size('||string_agg(a.attname::TEXT, ')+pg_column_size(')||') ), 0) FROM '||'public.my_test'
    FROM   pg_index i
    JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)
    WHERE  i.indrelid = (SELECT 'public.my_test'::regclass::oid)
    AND    i.indisprimary
    INTO v_query;


    EXECUTE v_query INTO v_result;
    raise notice '%', v_result;
END; $$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
```

Is there any way to do same, without PLPGSQL/dynamic query, but suing straight SQL?

Comment: That depends on your PostgreSQL version. Why not divide the index size by the number of rows? That will show a somewhat bigger result (`fillfactor = 90`), but one that is useful.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I use 11 version, but does 13 have something different with regard of this? "Why not divide the index size by the number of rows? " This will show index size per row right, how this is related to index columns total size? or i'm missing something?

Comment: Of course it is something different. I was just trying to guess why you want that. If it is academic interest: it is the size of the indexed data plus the site of a tuple identifier (6 bytes).